# How to save time that Tick in Chronometer with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, chronometer

As we know to save something like int value's we use this

```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putInt("Something", "Value");
   editor.commit();
        }
```

now my question how to save something like chronometer time with sharedpreferences? as we know chronometer code like this

```
    focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);      
    focus.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
            int h   = (int)(time /3600000);
            int m = (int)(time - h*3600000)/60000;
            int s= (int)(time - h*3600000- m*60000)/1000 ;
            String hh = h < 10 ? "0"+h: h+"";
            String mm = m < 10 ? "0"+m: m+"";
            String ss = s < 10 ? "0"+s: s+"";
            cArg.setText(hh+":"+mm+":"+ss);
        }
    });
```

to start the chronometer, put this in a button called "Button Start"

```
               focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
               focus.start();
```

to stop the chronometer, put this in a button called "Button Stop"

```
              focus.stop();
```

Ok, so my question is how to save the chronometer time/tick if "Button Stop" was pressed? Thank's

Comment: what is Chronometer ? is  it class ?

Comment: you are trying to save the last time?

Comment: @Elltz yup i trying to save the last time

Answer (score 0):

Using your terminology, you have to put this piece of code:

```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putInt("Something", "Value");
   editor.commit();
```

into your 'Button Stop' `OnClickListener`

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
  //here
  }
});
```

Comment: you mean like this? editor.putInt("Time", focus); is that?